# Existance of the integral in the domain of generator of the strongly continuous semigroup

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, semigroup-of-operators

Let $\{s(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ is a $C_0$ semigroup of bounded operator on the Banach space $X$ and $A:D(A)\subset X\rightarrow X$ be the infinitesimal generators of the semigroup $\{s(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$. Therefore the operator $A$ is densly defined and closed operator. Let $g\in L^1(0,T;D(A))$,then is it true that $\int_0^T s(T-p)g(p)dp$ will be in $D(A)$?  ${\int_0^T||s(T-p)g(p)||dp}$ is finite that part is ok. Help me

Comment: When you write $L^{1}(0,T;\mathcal{D}(A))$, do you mean that the function has values in $\mathcal{D}(A)$ as a subset of the Banach space $X$, or that it takes its values in the Banach space where the norm is the graph norm of $A$? I suspect it is the latter, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @T.A.E. if $D(A)$ has graph norm then D(A) is Banach space with respect to graph norm. Then value of the integral will be in D(A) . if $D(A)$ has norm as norm of $X$, then what will happen?

Comment: Everything may work out, but you can't apply $A$ to the function $g(p)$ and know anything its integrability.

Comment: @T.A.E. if $Ag(t)$ is integrable then the given integral may in $D(A)$?

Comment: I think so. You should be able to show $A\int_{0}^{T}s(T-p)g(p)\,dp=\int_{0}^{T}s(T-p)Ag(p)\,dp$. This will require knowing that $A$ is closed. An approximating sequence $\{ g_{n} \}$ for $g$ would be formed in the graph norm of $A$, and that should get you what you want, I believe.

Comment: @T.A.E. i agree with you. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, and thank you for the feedback.